# customizing a theme

Tags: customization, themes

I need some information about WordPress theme customization (or) editing
could anyone tell me what is the best ways to customize WordPress theme.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very very broad question, probably isn't the place for it tbh. But anyway, there are many many themes in existence already, you can modify them, generally by adding a child theme and making your modifications there, it is bad practice to update a theme directly.

If you wish to extend the functionality of your site, then maybe a plugin, custom or not may be a better solution for you. If you wish to add custom post types, meta fields etc, it is advisable to do this outside of the theme core files.

Again there are a vast array of plugins out there to extend and modify the look, functionality and usability of practically any type of site!

Start here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development